# struts character encoding problem in response html

Tags: html, character-encoding, struts

Please consider the following scenario. I have a form with a property:

```
class MyForm extends ActionForm{
    String myProperty;
    ... // getter & setters here
}
```

I set this property in action class:

```
class MyAction extends Action{
   ... // execute method begins here
   myForm.setMyProperty("<b>Hello World</b>");
   ... // execute method returns here
}
```

Now when I open the respective JSP page, I get following html at the point where the myProperty is supposed to be displayed:

```
&lt;b&gt;Hello World&lt;/b&gt;
```

Which is wrong. It is supposed to generate following html:

```
<b>Hello World</b>
```

Any ideas how can this problem be solved?

**EDIT**

The JSP code is as following:

```
<bean:write name="MyForm" property="myProperty"/>
```

Comment: Show the code that uses myProperty in the end, this code doesn't tell much.

Comment: @nodan... I have added the code that uses myProperty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the escapeXml attribute to preserve HTML formatting:

```
//your view *.jsp
<c:out value="${myProperty}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got hint from **baijiu**'s answer, and found the solution:

```
<bean:write name="MyForm" property="myProperty" filter="false"/>
```

Simply setting filter="false" displays sensitive characters as they are, without any encoding. Thanks **baijiu**.